# Why does my array need parsing, when they look the same in the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, json, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 component when a question springs to mind. As I'm experementing with different arrays, I'm wondering why they need different treatment of data, when they all contain the same.

First case: I have a 'hardcoded' array, which looks like the following:

```
var tmp = [
    {
        "Weight": 0.0,
        "Speed": 59.9,
        "Depth": 362.24000,
        "Time": "2014-04-09T10:01:23",
        "Id": 0
    }, {
        "Weight": 10.0,
        "Speed": 59.9,
        "Depth": 394.07000,
        "Time": "2014-04-09T10:01:56",
        "Id": 1
    }];
```

Or, when inspected in Chrome console:

[image]

Whenever I feed my component with this array, the component works fine and all lines / axis are drawn correctly.

Second case: I fetch an array from my controller using d3.json, and get the following returned when logging it to console:

```
[{"Weight":0.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":362.24000,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:01:23","Id":0},{"Weight":10.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":394.07000,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:01:56","Id":1}]
```

So, whenever I'm trying to do a `json.foreach()` (json is the name of the array from controller):

```
json.forEach(function(d) {
    var date = format(d.Time);
    d.Time = date;
});
```

I get an error saying the following when starting the foreach function:
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

In order for this to work, I had to do a `JSON.parse(json)` on the data returned from my controller through `d3.json()`, and then my array looks like the following:
[image]

I should also mention that my asp.net mvc controller returns this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Trend.ToArray());

return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I get the fact that my array returned from controller looks like a string of values when inspecting it, but I really don't understand why.

So, I guess my question really boils down to this;
Why does my array "tmp" work, but my array fetched with d3.json needs to be parsed before working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'tmp' array is parsed for you by the browser when the script is run. You can check this when you deliberately create a faulty array by for example place a double bracket somewhere.
Your browser will tell you it doesn't understand what you want the 'tmp' variable to be.

However, when you create a call to your MVC controller, it doesn't know beforehand what result type to expect from that controller. Maybe some other controller it will call later on in your application will return XML data, which needs another way of parsing.

An easier method to fetch JSON data from 'anywhere' is to use the jQuery [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method.
This requires no extra call to parse the data.

Also, what does you D3 call look like? What function did you declare to handle the callback?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.each(json, function (index, d) {
  var date = format(d.Time);
  d.Time = date;
});
```